# Listeners: OK to run on every page, or initialize only on pages that need them?

Tags: jquery, performance

On my site, I have elements with "event listeners" (.live, .bind, or .delegate) and I can divide these into groups based on how often they appear:

1. Elements that are on every page.
2. Elements that are on some pages.

If I have an element that is on every page, and that element requires a listener, then of course I just implement that listener site-wide.

I'm trying to figure out what that will be wisest for an element that both (a) appears only on a few pages, and (b) requires a listener:

- Implement the listener site-wide
- Implement the listener so that it must first be initialized on any page that wants to use it

For example, say I have 
`<input class='autocomplete' />` that appears on several pages, but not site-wide. When someone enters text, it hits the database and tries to complete their query for them.

Since this element doesn't appear on every page, is the overhead of `jQuery.live('someEventsHere',MyHandler())` high enough that I should only call it on pages where it is used? (E.g., by creating an `initializeMyHandler()` function and calling it on those pages?) Or, on pages where that listener will not be used, is this cheap enough to set anyway and not worry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live()` works by attaching your event handler to the document, not to the element. Thus, `live()` makes use of event bubbling, so attaching event handlers won't incur *that* much overhead, though there will admittedly be some. The HTTP request for the inclusion of a JavaScript file is more than the overhead incurred from attaching an unused event handler to the document.

Comment: I think that's good background on `.live()`, but I won't always be using live. Sometimes I'll be using the cheaper `.bind()`. Is this so cheap that calling 1 `.bind()` event on a page where it's not used is no big deal and not worth the hassle of setting up an `.initialize()` function to avoid calling `.bind()`? What about 10 `bind()` events on a page where only one or two will be used? 100 on a page where only one or two will actually be used?

Comment: `.bind()` attaches itself to the element, so you'll need to first check to see if the element is there (which requires a query to the DOM.) Querying the DOM 100 times simply to set up event handlers is not acceptable IMO. I believe the answer to your question is the same answer to the question: how many event handler initializations equal one HTTP request in terms of overhead?

Comment: Ahh, thanks for your comment; now I more clearly see what you were getting at with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will incur overhead from live() since it has to keep checking for elements whenever the DOM changes. Depending on your site traffic, this may be acceptable to you.

However, I'd say separate your code into files and include only the files you need on each page.

Comment: Currently, I have one master javascript file that is included on every page. This way, it's cached. I'm concerned that splitting this up into different files which are required on different pages would be equally confusing (from a dev perspective) as would calling .initialize() functions, but would incur the additional cost of having multiple HTTP requests for the different JS files.

Comment: @jpp One file's generally considered best-practice for load time, yes.

Comment: Actually, using a script loader that loads files in parallel (such as head.js) is now considered faster than one big file.